# How to find MCFG table without knowing EFI System table?

Tags: linux, bios, esxi, uefi

I'm working on a special OS(VMWare ESXi, a close source OS which looks based on linux), there is a requirement that I need to get physical address of MCFG table. Since the APIs are very limited, I can only map physical addresses but can't get base address of EFI system table or any other ACPI tables from the OS.

So is there any way to find MCFG table without knowing EFI System table?

Thanks.

Comment: `... a close source OS which looks based on linux), ...` IMHO this conflicts with the GPL2

Comment: @wildplasser: and this is relevant to the question how exactly?

Comment: Yes, IMO it is. **If** the OP violates the GPL, we should *at least* not help him/her.

Answer (score 1):

On a non-EFI system, software finds the RSDP by searching for its signature in memory. See http://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6_2.pdf#page169 section 5.2.5.1.

Although this method is not supported with EFI, it’s possible that your platform firmware still places the ACPI tables in a place where they can be found using that method.

If not, you’ll have to figure out a way to get the RSDP or XSDT from ESXi, which may require some reverse engineering.

You didn’t say much about what software you are writing and how it fits into the boot flow—-it’s possible that ESXi has already consumed the ACPI tables and reused the memory before your software gets control. In that case, you would be truly out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

dmesg | grep RSDP will give you the RSDP Physical Address. Note RSDP Addresses can only be retrieved programmatically inside a UEFI shell. Parse the output of the above command, use vmk_UserMap APIs to map the Physical Address Space into the userworld process's address space and from there get hold of XSDT and then from there MCFG.

If you are not interested in getting to the MCFG from RSDP->XSDT table, then you can directly run dmesg | grep MCFG on your hypervisor as well.